# how can i get value instead of Instance of 'Future<String>'

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter-sharedpreference

I'm using flutter and I am trying to get a value from shared_preferences for firebase.

i checked my cord doesn't work and uid was " **Instance of 'Future'** ".

the solution i found was using setState but i can't use that because it's not in Widget build.

in this situation, how can i get value(uid) instead of Instance of 'Future'

```
class MyItemProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  String uid = '';
  Future<void> getUid() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    uid = await prefs.getString('uid')!;
  }
  late CollectionReference itemsReference;
  List<Item> items = [];
  List<Item> find_result = [];

  MyItemProvider({reference}) {
    getUid();
    itemsReference = reference ?? FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(uid);
  }

...
...
...
```

i try to use setState
i checked 'print(uid);' was Instance of 'Future'

Answer (score 0):

You have to do following things

```
String uid = '';
  Future<String> getUid() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return await prefs.getString('uid')!;
  }
  late CollectionReference itemsReference;
  List<Item> items = [];
  List<Item> find_result = [];

  MyItemProvider({reference}) async {
    uid = await getUid();
    debugPrint('userId $uid');
    itemsReference = reference ?? FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(uid);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to await your Futute function "getUid" since it is a type of Future where it is being called.

But you can further your knowledge in dart asynchronous programming, read [this](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Answer (score 0):

You can use then() method since it returns the value from Future

```dart
 MyItemProvider({reference}) {
    getUid().then((uid) {
        itemsReference = reference ?? FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(uid);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Or you can do just like @Rohan Jariwala's answer